# Best practice: how to increment not existing element of array

Tags: php, arrays, increment, null-coalescing

I want to increment a value of an array, which is potentially not existing yet.

```
$array = [];
$array['nonExistentYet']++; // Notice
```

**Problem**

This leads to a *NOTICE*.

**Attempt**

I found a way to do this, but its kinda [clunky](https://3v4l.org/D7OsK):

```
$array = [];
$array['nonExistentYet'] = ($array['nonExistentYet'] ?? 0) + 1;
```

**Question**

Is there a more human readable/elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My standard implementation for this is:

```
if (isset($array['nonExistentYet']))
   $array['nonExistentYet']++;
else
   $array['nonExistentYet'] = 1;
```

But this is one of the rarely scenarios where I use the `@` operator to suppress warnings, but only if I have full control over the array:

```
@$array['nonExistentYet']++;
```

Generally, it is not good to suppress warnings or error messages!

Comment: totally banned the `@` from my coding, but this is indeed a good use for it, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If this is used often, you can define a little helper method, which also uses an interesting side effect...

```
function inc(&$element) {
    $element++;
}
$array = [];
inc($array['nonExistentYet']);
print_r($array);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [nonExistentYet] => 1
)
```

with no warning.
As you can see the function defines the parameter as `&$element`, if this value doesn't exist, then it will be created, so the function call itself will create the element and then it will just increment it.

Comment: Huh, this is not causing a notice? But why - it totally should 0_o

Answer (score 2):

well i guess a more readable way would be to use `if..else` as,

```
$arr = [];
if(array_key_exists('nonExistentYet', $arr)) {
    $arr['nonExistentYet'] += 1;
}
else {
    $arr['nonExistentYet'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Its more readable, but even more clunky - thanks for the contribution though :)

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is a little vague,
Either the variable exists and you increment it, or it does not exist in this case you create it.
In another case suppose that you want to do it in a for loop, in this case you do not have to worry about the existence of the variable.

Comment: When i do a group count on an array the element might not exist. Thats why i said it potentially :)

Comment: Ok I see. You can use key_exists($value, $array) to verify if $value exist in $array. This function return true or false

Answer (score -1):

One way is ternary operator, which checks if array value exists:

```
$array['iDoNotExistYet'] = empty($array['iDoNotExistYet']) ? 1 : ++$array['iDoNotExistYet'];
```

Other one would be just rewriting it to `if` and `else` condition.

Comment: I'd rather prefer the if - ternary is super-un-humanreadable :D

Comment: This will not work. My php assigns always 1 if the value is 1 before. The `x++` increments x to 2, but its previous value `1` is assigned to x. More exact, the result is undefined and implementation dependent, because php can also decide to assign first and then to increment. The keyword for this is `Sequence point`.

Comment: Just need to replace `$array['iDoNotExistYet']++` by `$array['iDoNotExistYet']+1` - just a typo i guess - but the point was the ternary which is absolutely fine - i just dont like to use it because of extra bainjuice :D

Comment: I edited to use preincrement, which first increments and then returns value.